# How to add country drop down using openUI5

Tags: sapui5

Is there's a simple way to create a country drop down using openUI5? or a sample that i can be use to create a drop down list of country.

Comment: Yes, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/50934253/5846045

Answer (score 2):

Well it seems like you've tried nothing to solve your problem, but I'll give it a shot anyway.

You need a list of countries, preferably in a non-human readable format (JSON). You can find such lists via google (`list of countries json`).
You then use this JSON list to create a new `sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel`. After that, bind the model to your view.

Your view should contain a `sap.m.Select` which references your bound model in its `items` aggregation.

Example on how to bind data: http://openui5.org/getstarted.html#step5

Example on how to use select: https://openui5beta.netweaver.ondemand.com/explored.html#/entity/sap.m.Select/samples

Comment: UI5 actually does provide a list of countries already (via CLDR) which can be easily transformed into a JSONModel: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50934253/5846045.
Never used in the production though. What do you think? :)