# Create Country List from JSON

Tags: json, sapui5

I am trying to create a combo box with a list of countries in SAP UI5.

I have created a combo box and have created dynamic list of some countries, but to create more than 100 countries, the only easy way is to create a JSON file of countries and then populate in Controller.js.

I tried to create a JSON file but I am unsure whether I have to store it under *model folder* or *root*.

What changes do I have to make in my XML view and controller, and where should I attach `countries.json` file?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at something called as "Aggregation Binding" [Aggregation Binding in XML views](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/19eabf5b13214f27b929b9473df3195b)

Here is an example to refer to which explains

- How to create a model using data from json file
- How to Bind model data to the XML view control(you have to bind comboBox instead of table)

> [How to bind json data model to an XML view](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/bf71375454654b44af01379a3c3a6273)

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't need to create the `countries.json` file at all :)

As UI5 leverages [Common Locale Data Repository](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Locale_Data_Repository) (CLDR) internally and provides the data via  `sap.ui.core.LocaleData`<sup>[API](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.core.LocaleData)</sup>, which includes language names, **country names**, currency names, singular/plural modifications, and more..

A list of supported regions for the locale data are stored in a JSON format [here](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/tree/master/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/core/cldr).  In one of those files, if you look at the property `"territories"`, you'll see that the country names are listed among them. You can filter every irrelevant territory out that is not considered a country, and then bind the rest in the `items` aggregation of the combo box.

## Demo

```js
sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(() => sap.ui.require([
  "sap/ui/core/Locale",
  "sap/ui/core/LocaleData",
  "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel",
  "sap/ui/core/mvc/XMLView",
], function(Locale, LocaleData, JSONModel, XMLView) {
  "use strict";

  XMLView.create({
    definition: `<mvc:View xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core" xmlns="sap.m"
      height="100%"
      displayBlock="true">
      <ComboBox class="sapUiTinyMargin"
        width="15rem"
        placeholder="Select a country.."
        filterSecondaryValues="true"
        showSecondaryValues="true"
        items="{
          path: '/',
          templateShareable: false,
          key: 'code',
          sorter: { path: 'name' }
        }">
        <core:ListItem xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
          key="{code}"
          text="{name}"
          additionalText="{code}" />
      </ComboBox>
    </mvc:View>`,
    models: createCountryModel(getCountries()),
  }).then(view => view.placeAt("content"));

  function createCountryModel(countries, sizeLimit = 300) {
    const model = new JSONModel(countries);
    model.setSizeLimit(sizeLimit);
    model.setDefaultBindingMode("OneWay");
    return model;
  }

  function getCountries() {
    const territories = getTerritories();
    return extractCountriesFrom(territories, byCustomCheck());
  }

  function getTerritories(localeId) {
    const currentConfig = sap.ui.getCore().getConfiguration();
    const locale = localeId ? new Locale(localeId) : currentConfig.getLocale();
    const localeData = new LocaleData(locale);
    return localeData.getTerritories(); // includes country names
  }

  function extractCountriesFrom(territories, customCheck = () => true) {
    const isValidCountry = createCountryCheck(customCheck);
    const toObject = code => Object.freeze({
      code: code,
      name: territories[code],
    });
    const countryObjects = Object.keys(territories)
      .filter(isValidCountry)
      .map(toObject);
    return Object.freeze(countryObjects);
  }
  
  function createCountryCheck(customCheck, obviouslyNotCountries = [
    "EU", // "European Union"
    "EZ", // "Eurozone"
    "UN", // "United Nations"
    "ZZ", // "Unknown Region"
  ]) {
    return territoryCode => territoryCode.length == 2
      && !obviouslyNotCountries.includes(territoryCode)
      && customCheck(territoryCode);
  }

  function byCustomCheck() { // returns a function that returns boolean
    // E.g.: list of sanctioned countries you want to exclude
    const list = [
      "AF",
      "KP",
      "IR",
      // ...
    ];
    return countryCode => !list.includes(countryCode);
  }

}));
```

```html
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap" src="https://ui5.sap.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
  data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.core, sap.m"
  data-sap-ui-theme="sap_fiori_3"
  data-sap-ui-async="true"
  data-sap-ui-compatversion="edge"
  data-sap-ui-xx-waitfortheme="init"
></script>
<body id="content" class="sapUiBody sapUiSizeCompact"></body>
```

As you can see in the example, the ComboBox is successfully populated with the countries. When a new `LocaleData` instance is created, a request is sent immediately (currently [via sync XHR](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/daa63a66c92e4061722d2eb9c45696b9b1667a56/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/core/LocaleData.js#L3162-L3165)) to get the data which are translated in the language that [UI5 detects from the client settings](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/91f21f176f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html#loio91f21f176f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070__section_6CAF7D95C27C487CB201CE83345AC370). If no language could be detected, the [`en.json`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap/ui/core/cldr/en.json) file will be retrieved.<sup>[src](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/daa63a66c92e4061722d2eb9c45696b9b1667a56/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/core/Configuration.js#L69)</sup>

The above approach has the following advantages:

- No need to create and maintain a separate "country" list. ✔️
- Multilingual support ✔️
- Reusability ✔️ - When UI5 tries to fetch the same locale data file, which is the case when e.g. a [Calendar](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.ui.unified.sample.CalendarMinMax/preview) is used, the browser can serve the file quickly from the *cache* since the same file was already fetched before.

---

### Note

When creating a `JSONModel` to store more than 100 country names, keep in mind to increase the [size limit](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.Model/methods/setSizeLimit) as well. The current default limit is `100`.