# json list have no values or the text is invisible

Tags: json, dropdown

When trying to access the list from the Json files for the combo box the text is invisible

Attached is the XML and JS:

```
{
        "text":"Sweden",
        "key":"SE"
        },
        {
        "text":"United Kingdom",
        "key":"GB"
        }
            ]
}
```

JS view:

```
  var oModel = new JSONModel("countries.json");
  oModel.setProperty("/comboBoxtext", "");
  oModel.setProperty("/comboBoxKey", "");
  this.getView().setModel(oModel,"mCountry");
```

When I click the combo box the dropdown is just empty list or no text is seen in the list

I see my key defined in xml, do you think something missing in *Controller.js* ?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you enlarge the scope a little bit and reveal the project language and eventually framework?

Comment: SAP UI5 , json list is seen invisible from combo box

Comment: @Chetanpoojary Here I demoed how to create a simple list of countries without `countries.json`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50934253/5846045 which you can use in your application. Please let us know if that answer could solve the issue or if that would be helpful for other readers (See _[What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers))._